# If a subset of a vector space is closed under scalar multiplication, then why do we also need to prove the existence of the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$, then we can show that $0 \cdot x = z$, where $x,z \in V$ and $z$ is the zero vector. Then if we show that for some subset $W$ of $V$ that $c \cdot x \in W$ for all $c\in F$ and $x \in W$, would it not be redundant to prove $z \in W$?

In other words, can I prove that a subset of $V$ is a subspace of $V$ by simply showing that it's closed under addition and scalar multiplication?

Comment: The empty set is trivially closed under addition and scalar multiplication. A vector space has to be nonempty.

Comment: Since you said "for all $c$" you have stated that $0 \cdot x = z$ is in the subset but this is trivial since you've tacitly assumed the result.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Assumed what, $0 \cdot x = z$? If $0$ is the additive identity of $F$, then $0\cdot x + 0 \cdot x = (0+0)\cdot x = 0\cdot x = 0\cdot x + z$. Then by the cancellation law of vector addition, we get the desired result.

Comment: You said for all $c \in F$ which means $c=0$ is one of those cases.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Doesn't closure under scalar multiplication assume for all $c \in F$?

Comment: Yeah, and you assumed closure so that means you assumed $0 \cdot x$ is in $W$. You're intuition is perfectly correct, you don't have to prove it again separately if you've already proved it. Tacit assumptions can be hard to spot but it's useful to know what they are. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_assumption

Comment: Your reasoning is perfectly valid if there *is* an $x \in W$, i.e. if $W$ is nonempty. Your reasoning is invalid if $W$ is empty. This is why you need the additional assumption that $W$ contains at least one element.

Comment: @Bungo Why are the other conditions of a vector space (associativity of vector addition, etc.) not also trivial for the empty set?

Comment: @hiroshin They are. The only thing that stops the empty set from being a vector space is that it doesn't contain the zero element.

Comment: @Bungo Also, instead of trivial do you mean vacuous?

Comment: Yes, I meant vacuously true.

Comment: @Bungo I got it, thank you!!